How does OKx smart account work with Uniswap and 1inch?
To my understanding, with ERC-4337 AA smart account, users are submitting user ops to the bundler service instead of an ordinary ethereum transaction to the RPC. Therefore, I used to assume that DApps will have to make implementation to create user ops in order to get AA supported.
However, when I tried to make a swap on Uniswap and 1inch with my OKx smart account, it was able to complete a swap as a ERC-4337 transaction. I have looked into Uniswap interface code and they don't seems to have built anything related to AA. I know that WalletConnect sort of supporting AA smart account but they doesn't seem to do the translation. Does anyone has idea on how does OKx smart account or other AA wallets do the trick?
The reason of asking is if I build my own DApps, do I have to build specific logic to support AA transaction?

I think I got the answer myself. Obviously OKx wallet is not an open-sourced so this is just the best guess. I found that in WalletConnect web wallet example, they are using a library called permissionless.js. In this library, once a smartAccountClient is initialised, it has a function sendTransactions which will take the to, value and data from an ordinary transaction and send it as an userops to the configured bundler service.
const hash = await smartAccountClient.sendTransaction({
    to: "0x0488bEE1Ec682db0F0E74AB52faFdDdEf10Af123",
    data: encodeFunctionData({
        abi: [parseAbiItem('function mint()')]
    }),
    value: 0n
})

Thus, a dApp does not have to implement anything to handle ERC-4337 transaction as long as the wallet will do it for them.
